# IF statements inside function do not recognize conditions

Tags: r, function, if-statement, plot, vector

I want to adjust my function so that my `if` and `else if` statements recognize the name of the dataframe used and execute the correct plotting function. These are some mock data structured the same as mine:

```
df1<-data.frame(A=c(1,2,2,3,4,5,1,1,2,3),
                B=c(4,4,2,3,4,2,1,5,2,2),
                C=c(3,3,3,3,4,2,5,1,2,3),
                D=c(1,2,5,5,5,4,5,5,2,3),
                E=c(1,4,2,3,4,2,5,1,2,3),
                dummy1=c("yes","yes","no","no","no","no","yes","no","yes","yes"),
                dummy2=c("high","low","low","low","high","high","high","low","low","high"))

df1[colnames(df1)] <- lapply(df1[colnames(df1)], factor)


vals <- colnames(df1)[1:5]
dummies <- colnames(df1)[-(1:5)]
step1 <- lapply(dummies, function(x) df1[, c(vals, x)])
step2 <- lapply(step1, function(x) split(x, x[, 6]))
names(step2) <- dummies
tbls <- unlist(step2, recursive=FALSE)
tbls<-lapply(tbls, function(x) x[(names(x) %in% names(df1[c(1:5)]))])

A<-lapply(tbls,"[", c(1,2))
B<-lapply(tbls,"[", c(3,4))
C<-lapply(tbls,"[", c(3,4))
list<-list(A,B,C)
names(list)<-c("A","B","C")
```

And this is my function:

```
plot_1<-function (section, subsample) {
  data<-list[grep(section, names(list))]
  data<-data[[1]]
  name=as.character(names(data))
  
  if(section=="A" && subsample=="None"){plot_likert_general_section(df1[c(1:2)],"A")}
  
  else if (section==name && subsample=="dummy1"){plot_likert(data$dummy1.yes, title=paste("How do the",name,"topics rank?"));plot_likert(data$Ldummy1.no, title = paste("How do the",name,"topics rank?"))}
}
```

Basically what I want it to do is plot a certain graph by specifying section and subsample I'm interested in if, for example, I want to plot section C and subsample dummy.1, I just write:

`plot_1(section="C", subsample="dummy1)`

I want to avoid writing this:

```
else if (section=="A" && subsample=="dummy1"){plot_likert(data$dummy1.yes, title=paste("How do the A topics rank?"));plot_likert(data$Ldummy1.no, title = paste("How do the A topics rank?"))}
  else if (section=="B" && subsample=="dummy1"){plot_likert(data$dummy1.yes, title=paste("How do the B topics rank?"));plot_likert(data$Ldummy1.no, title = paste("How do the B topics rank?"))}
  else if (section=="C" && subsample=="dummy1"){plot_likert(data$dummy1.yes, title=paste("How do the c topics rank?"));plot_likert(data$Ldummy1.no, title = paste("How do the C topics rank?"))}
  else if (section=="C" && subsample=="dummy2")...
  .
  .
  }
```

So I tried to extract the dataframe used from the list so that it matches the string of the section typed in the function (`data<-list[grep(section, names(list))]`) and store its name as a character (`name=as.character(names(data))`), because I thought that in this way the function would have recognized the string "A", "B" or "C" by itself, without the need for me to specify each condition.

However, if I run it, I get this error: `Warning message: In section == name && subsample == "dummy1" : 'length(x) = 4 > 1' in coercion to 'logical(1)'`, that, from what I understand, is due to the presence of a vector in the statement. But I have no idea how to correct for this (I'm still quite new to R).

How can I fix the function so that it does what I want? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should really pass data into your function as an argument. Don't write functions that rely on objects in your global environment having certain names, like `list` here. It makes the functions much less flexible and portable, as well as more bug-prone.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will fix this... Do you have any advice on how to resolve the warning?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can't really test your code without the `plot_likert_general_section` function or the `plot_likert` function, but I've done a bit of simplifying and best practices--passing `list` in as an argument, consistent spaces and assignment operators, etc.--and this is my best guess as to what you want:

```
plot_1 = function(list, section, subsample) { ## added `list` as an argument
  data = list[[grep(section, names(list))]] # use [[ to extract a single item
  name = as.character(names(data))
  
  if(subsample == "None"){
    plot_likert_general_section(df1[c(1:2)], section)
  } else  {
    yesno = paste(subsample, c("yes", "no"), sep = ".")
    plot_likert(data[[yesno[1]]], title = paste("How do the", name, "topics rank?"))
    plot_likert(data[[yesno[2]]], title = paste("How do the", name, "topics rank?"))
  }
}

plot_1(list, section = "C", subsample = "dummy1)
```

I'm not sure if your `plot_likert` functions use base or grid graphics--but either way you'll need to handle the multiple plots. With `base`, probably use `mfrow()` to display both of them, if grid I'd suggest putting them in a `list` to return them both, and then maybe using `gridExtra::grid.arrange()` (or similar) to plot both of them.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that the error is due to passing a vector where a single value is expected.  Try inserting print statements before the equality test to diagnose why this is.

Also, be careful with choosing variable names like `name` which are baseR functions (e.g. `?name`).  I'd also recommend following the tidyverse style guide here: https://style.tidyverse.org/.